# Can all nine essential amino acids be produced synthetically?

Tags: amino-acids

I would like to know if all nine of the essential amino acids can be produced synthetically with high purity without amines or other impurities through microbial activity during the production process.

Comment: If you're using microbes, it's not synthetic. You can use the Strecker reaction otherwise: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strecker_amino_acid_synthesis But you'll need a resolution for the desired enantiomer.